# MDN constructor property explanation confusion

Tags: javascript

I'm reading [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) about `constructor` property and it states the following:

> Returns a reference to the Object function that created the instance's
>   prototype.

And they give an example:

```
function Tree(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var theTree = new Tree('Redwood');
console.log('theTree.constructor is ' + theTree.constructor);
```

Here the instance is `theTree` and its prototype is `Object.getPrototypeOf(theTree)`, which is Object function, not `Tree`. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Well, `Tree` *is* an "Object function". It probably just depends on the particulars of your debugging environment/browser whether the name is resolved to and displayed as `Tree` or just this generic "Object function".

Comment: @deceze, but `Tree` didn't create `theTree`'s prototype, it created the instance. This is a confusing part

Comment: Don't cast stuff to string in `console.log()`, it hides important details.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, thanks, it's not me, it's MDN guys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototype of an object is typically inherited from its constructor function:

```
function Tree() {}
Tree.prototype.foo = function () {};

var theTree = new Tree();
```

`theTree` now has `theTree.foo` from its *prototype chain*. The `function Tree` initialised the object, and is also responsible for the contents of its prototype chain. That's why they express it as *"the Object function that created the instance's prototype"*.

Comment: I see now, thanks. So basically `constructor` property is more relevant to finding out where object's prototype came from, then to understanding what function was used to create an object?

Comment: I think it's rather debatable whether MDN could write that sentence in a more straight forward manner. What `.constructor` is "more relevant to" depends on what you want to use it for; and quite honestly I've never had the need to use it for anything so far, so I'm not in the best position to comment on that.

Comment: I see, thanks. I think it might be relevant to `prototype` since it can be used in inheritance checks like this `theTree instanceof Tree`, and if `Tree` created the prototype for `theTree`, than `Tree.prototype` must be in `theTree`s prototype chain. Do you think that assumption is good enough?

Comment: Yes, you're probably using `.constructor` *indirectly* all the time with things like `instanceof`.

Answer (score 0):

Object.getPrototypeOf(theTree) is the prototype of your Tree function

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(theTree) == Tree.prototype; // true
```

Both refer the same object

And  Tree.prototype has the property named 'constructor' which is infact a reference to the Tree function only

```
theTree.contructor == Tree.prototype.constructor ;// true
```

Basically theTree has a proto link (____proto____) and this proto link points to the Tree.prototype.
So when you do theTree.constructor it actually follows the proto link and reaches Tree.prototype and finds the constructor which itself it Tree function